# Not able to open static html file content using Jquery Boxy along with Code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using code igniter 1.7.3 and my static html files are resides under "businesscaliber\system\application\views" folder. Also I am using Jquery Boxy plugin. but when I click on **Remote content** link it is not going to display partial.html content.

```
<a href='/partial.html' class='boxy' title='AJAX Content Demo'>Remote content (partial.html)</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  $('.boxy').boxy();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does it at least try to load anything? Is the URL correct? Firebug can help to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your partial.html file is in the root directory and if your using .htaccess to rewrite URL's try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to have a static html files in the root directory

**ex**

Root
-system [DIR]
-aplication [DIR]
-staticHtmlDir [DIR]
--partial.html [FILE]

Your url should be as follows;

```
<a href='staticHtmlDir/partial.html' class='boxy' title='AJAX Content Demo'>Remote content (partial.html)</a>
```

**OR YOU CAN THIS WAY**

controller file

```
<?php
class MyClass extends Controller {

public function MyClass() {

parent::Controller();
}

public function showRemoteHtml() {

$this->load->view('partial');
}

}

/* End of file Myclass.php */
```

Your url should be as follows;

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Myclass/showRemoteHtml'); ?>" class='boxy' title='AJAX Content Demo'>Remote content (partial.html)</a>
```

Comment: when i tried with this solution it gives An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: partial.php because $this->load->view('partial'); looks for PHP only